# Typescript causing errors with React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working in an Angular project that we are in the first phases of implementing React (eventually rewriting the app entirely in React, but has not been approved yet).  The project also uses Typescript, which is where my problem is coming from.  I am trying to use React-Router-Dom to navigate the pages inside the app, but Typescript keeps throwing errors similar to these below.  I have upgraded everything to the newest versions but I still get the same errors.  I have also uninstalled and reinstalled Typescript, as I have seen in other post.  Can someone please help me figure this out?  At this point I don't care if the solution it to get Typescript to ignore the React-Router-Dom altogether, I am just sick of this issue.

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts:161:61 - error TS1110: Type expected.

161 declare type _PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends `${infer L}/${infer R}` ? _PathParam<L> | _PathParam<R> : Path extends `:${infer Param}` ? Param : never;
                                                                ~~~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts:161:70 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

161 declare type _PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends `${infer L}/${infer R}` ? _PathParam<L> | _PathParam<R> : Path extends `:${infer Param}` ? Param : never;
                                                                         ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts:161:71 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

161 declare type _PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends `${infer L}/${infer R}` ? _PathParam<L> | _PathParam<R> : Path extends `:${infer Param}` ? Param : never;
                                                                          ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts:161:73 - error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.

161 declare type _PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends `${infer L}/${infer R}` ? _PathParam<L> | _PathParam<R> : Path extends `:${infer Param}` ? Param : never;

../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts:171:85 - error TS1110: Type expected.

171 declare type PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends "*" ? "*" : Path extends `${infer Rest}/*` ? "*" | _PathParam<Rest> : _PathParam<Path>;       
                                                                                        ~~~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts:171:94 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

171 declare type PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends "*" ? "*" : Path extends `${infer Rest}/*` ? "*" | _PathParam<Rest> : _PathParam<Path>;       
                                                                                                 ~~~~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts:171:98 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

171 declare type PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends "*" ? "*" : Path extends `${infer Rest}/*` ? "*" | _PathParam<Rest> : _PathParam<Path>;       
                                                                                                     ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:15:5 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

15     get basename(): RouterInit["basename"];
       ~~~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:15:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

15     get basename(): RouterInit["basename"];
           ~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:15:19 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

15     get basename(): RouterInit["basename"];
                     ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:22:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

22     get state(): RouterState;
           ~~~~~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:22:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

22     get state(): RouterState;
                  ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:29:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

29     get routes(): AgnosticDataRouteObject[];
           ~~~~~~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:29:17 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

29     get routes(): AgnosticDataRouteObject[];
                   ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:29:43 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

29     get routes(): AgnosticDataRouteObject[];

../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:38:17 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

38     initialize(): Router;
                   ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:47:17 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

47     subscribe(fn: RouterSubscriber): () => void;
                   ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:47:36 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

47     subscribe(fn: RouterSubscriber): () => void;
                                      ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:47:48 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

47     subscribe(fn: RouterSubscriber): () => void;
                                                  ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:59:49 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

59     enableScrollRestoration(savedScrollPositions: Record<string, number>, getScrollPosition: GetScrollPositionFunction, getKey?: GetScrollRestorationKeyFunction): () => void;
                                                   ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:59:73 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

59     enableScrollRestoration(savedScrollPositions: Record<string, number>, getScrollPosition: GetScrollPositionFunction, getKey?: GetScrollRestorationKeyFunction): () => void;
                                                                           ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:59:92 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

59     enableScrollRestoration(savedScrollPositions: Record<string, number>, getScrollPosition: GetScrollPositionFunction, getKey?: GetScrollRestorationKeyFunction): () => void;
                                                                                              ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:59:128 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

59     enableScrollRestoration(savedScrollPositions: Record<string, number>, getScrollPosition: GetScrollPositionFunction, getKey?: GetScrollRestorationKeyFunction): () => void;
                                                                                                                                  ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:59:162 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

59     enableScrollRestoration(savedScrollPositions: Record<string, number>, getScrollPosition: GetScrollPositionFunction, getKey?: GetScrollRestorationKeyFunction): () => void;

       ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:59:174 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

59     enableScrollRestoration(savedScrollPositions: Record<string, number>, getScrollPosition: GetScrollPositionFunction, getKey?: GetScrollRestorationKeyFunction): () => void;

                   ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:67:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

67     navigate(to: number): void;
                  ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:67:25 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

67     navigate(to: number): void;
                           ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:67:31 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

67     navigate(to: number): void;
                                 ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:73:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

73     navigate(to: To, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                  ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:73:27 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

73     navigate(to: To, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                             ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:73:51 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

73     navigate(to: To, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                                                     ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:73:57 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

73     navigate(to: To, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                                                           ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:85:14 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

85     fetch(key: string, routeId: string, href: string, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:85:31 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

85     fetch(key: string, routeId: string, href: string, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                                 ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:85:45 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

85     fetch(key: string, routeId: string, href: string, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                                               ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:85:60 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

85     fetch(key: string, routeId: string, href: string, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                                                              ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:85:84 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

85     fetch(key: string, routeId: string, href: string, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                                                                                      ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:85:90 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

85     fetch(key: string, routeId: string, href: string, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): void;
                                                                                            ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:92:17 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

92     revalidate(): void;
                   ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:92:23 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

92     revalidate(): void;
                         ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:100:24 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

100     createHref(location: Location | URL): string;
                           ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:100:41 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

100     createHref(location: Location | URL): string;
                                            ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:109:22 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

109     encodeLocation(to: To): Path;
                         ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:109:27 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

109     encodeLocation(to: To): Path;
                              ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:117:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

117     getFetcher<TData = any>(key?: string): Fetcher<TData>;
                         ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:117:33 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

117     getFetcher<TData = any>(key?: string): Fetcher<TData>;
                                    ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:117:42 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

117     getFetcher<TData = any>(key?: string): Fetcher<TData>;
                                             ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:117:58 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

117     getFetcher<TData = any>(key?: string): Fetcher<TData>;
                                                             ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:125:23 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

125     deleteFetcher(key?: string): void;
                          ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:125:32 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

125     deleteFetcher(key?: string): void;
                                   ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:125:38 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

125     deleteFetcher(key?: string): void;
                                         ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:132:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

132     dispose(): void;
                 ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:132:20 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

132     dispose(): void;
                       ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:139:60 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

139     _internalFetchControllers: Map<string, AbortController>;
                                                               ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:146:56 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

146     _internalActiveDeferreds: Map<string, DeferredData>;
                                                           ~
../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.d.ts:147:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

147 }
    ~
```

maintain.tsx

```
// Material-UI Imports
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
// React Imports
import * as React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
// React Component Imports
import Departments from '../../../react-components/maintain-pages/departments';
import Equipment from '../../../react-components/maintain-pages/equipment';
import Locations from '../../../react-components/maintain-pages/locations';
import Ltm from '../../../react-components/maintain-pages/ltm';
import Matrix from '../../../react-components/maintain-pages/matrix';
import { NavBar } from '../../../react-components/navbar/NavBar';

const Maintain = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Box className={classes.root} sx={{margin: '24px 0px 0px 24px'}}>
        <h1>Maintain</h1>

        <NavBar/>
        <Routes>
           <Route path='/' element='' />  
           <Route path='/ltm' element={<Ltm />}/>
           <Route path='/matrix' element={<Matrix />}/>
           <Route path='/equipment' element={<Equipment />}/>
           <Route path='/departments' element={<Departments />}/>
           <Route path='/locations' element={<Locations />}/>
        </Routes>

      </Box>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Maintain;
```

NavBar.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBarStyling.css';

// NavLinks
const menuItems = [
    {id: 1, label: 'LTM', path: '/ltm'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Matrix', path: '/matrix'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Equipment', path: '/equipment'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Departments', path: '/departments'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Locations', path: '/locations'},
];

// tslint:disable: no-shadowed-variable
export const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <nav className='nav'>
            <ul>
                {menuItems.map(menuItems => (
                    <li key={menuItems.id} >
                        <NavLink to={menuItems.path} >
                            {menuItems.label}
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "flow-babel-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have `react-router-dom@6.6.2` installed. RRDv6 is written completely in Typescript. There's no need to use `@types/react-router-dom` typings as a dev dependency.

Remove `@types/react-router-dom` from the project with either of the following commands run from the project's root directory.

```
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/react-router
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/react-router-dom
```

```
npm un -D @types/react-router
npm un -D @types/react-router-dom
```

This removes the dev dependency and updates the package.json file.

Also make sure you are using the same version of `react` and `react-dom`... these two libraries are always used in lock-step.

```
npm i -S react@18 react-dom@18
```

Find and install the appropriate `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I have updated the dependencies like you said (see above), but still getting the same error. Anything else that you can think of?

Comment: @Mtullis There may be something in the way you are importing/using RRD components. Can you edit your post to include the component code showing the imports and rendering of the router and routes, and links?

Comment: sure, here is my maintain page that I am trying to ad the navigation inside.  Being an Angular project (and I really don't know Angular) I tried wrapping the page content with the <BrowserRouter>, rather than the <App /> component that I typically would.  this maintain page works as a React wrapper inside the Angular project. Users are to navigate to this page, and have then access multiple other pages from here.